# Migrating from Heroku shared database to Heroku Postgres; Heroku Postgres plan choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I am building a rails application and I am currently hosting it on the Cedar stack on Heroku. The application has a postgres database and I am currently using the Heroku shared database. I understand the Heroku shared database is getting replaced soon.

My application's database is quite big and will have data added to it everyday. If I understood correctly the shared database replacement will allow you to have 10000 rows if you want to remain on the free option. My application will definitely have more than 10000 rows and I think it will fall in the next bracket of database size (the US$7 or US$9 per month).

Could someone clarify which database structure would be my next option if I exceed the 10000 rows maximum?

How do I configure my application to start using this database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's documentation seems to cover this pretty well. See [How to migrate between a shared database and Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres) and [migrating between plans](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-data-between-plans).

What do you need to know or what is giving you trouble that isn't covered there?

As for plan choice: Your database is moderately active and big. You're likely to have to pay to host it somewhere, and the $9/month starter plan looks reasonable, with a 10 million record limit. Heroku discusses plan size choice here: [Choosing the right postgres plan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cache-size), though it's more focused on the production plans that vary in cache size rather than having a DB size or row count limit.